# Manual Login Functionality for Twitter to make a tweet only in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter-oauth

I have made a tweet Functionality in my Application.
Its working fine.
now I don't want twitter Default Authentication (ie.login) Screen for login.
I want to put my custom login screen which has two text field of username and password.
and one tweet button.
now on tweet button click I want to direct post tweet on twitter like old twitter modules.
I heart that its done using Xouth . 
if it is possible then any code or links for that??

I want any solution for that???..
it is happen in BBC ipad App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Manual Login , you need Xauth Twitter Access ,

refer these source codes & Links,

http://code.google.com/p/tweetero/

https://github.com/aral/XAuthTwitterEngine